# Calculations inside Click command

Tags: autohotkey

Here is simple code:

```
f1::
    winGetActiveStats, title, width, height, topLeftX, topLeftY

    ;Doesn't work:
    ;click, %width% - 30, %height% - 30

    ;As well as this:
    ;click, (%width% - 30), (%height% - 30)

    ;Works fine:
    x := width - 30, y := height - 30
    click, %x%, %y%
return
```

For some reason 1st and 2nd examples doesn't work. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: you can't fix it. The documentation states *"%x%, %y%: Since click does not support expressions, variables should be enclosed in percent signs."* -- https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm

So if you need do to this often you could create a function

```
f1::
    MyClick()
return

MyClick()
    {
     winGetActiveStats, title, width, height, topLeftX, topLeftY
     x := width - 30, y := height - 30
     Click, %x%, %y%
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a wrapper function for the `Click` command:

```
Click(x, y)
{
    Click %x%, %y%
}
```

And use this code:

```
f1::
    winGetActiveStats, title, width, height, topLeftX, topLeftY
    Click(width - 30, height - 30)
    return
```

This can also be done for commands like `WinGetActiveStats`, using `ByRef`:

```
WinGetActiveStats(ByRef title, ByRef width, ByRef height, ByRef topLeftX, ByRef topLeftY)
{
    WinGetActiveStats title, width, height, topLeftX, topLeftY
}
```

The result is a clean, consistent, and straightforward way of calling commands, similar to C:

```
f1::
    WinGetActiveStats(title, width, height, topLeftX, topLeftY)
    Click(width - 30, height - 30)
    return
```

This can be done with almost all AutoHotkey commands and makes programming AutoHotkey quite a lot easier and the code more readable, eliminating all use of `%…%` in the main code. I personally have a module with wrapper functions for almost all commands in AutoHotkey – hopefully I will put it online one day.

Answer (score 2):

This uses `Click` with expressions by using [expression mode](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm):

```
winGetActiveStats, title, width, height, topLeftX, topLeftY
click % width - 30 "," height - 30
```